# How to get a using/typedef type to a function pointer automatically, given a forward declaration of some free function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef, using

How to get a `using/typedef` type to a function pointer automatically, given a forward declaration of some free function?

```cpp
// forward declaration of some functions
int f1(char**);
void f2(int, char*);

// manual declaration of function pointer types
using f1_t = int (*)(char**);
using f2_t = void (*)(int, char*);

// what I want to do: declaration of function pointer types with *automatic function type extraction*
using f1_t2 = some_magic(f1);
using f2_t2 = some_magic(f2);

// using types
f1_t2 f1p; // the same as f1_t f1p
f2_t2 f2p; // the same as f2_t f2p

/* ... */
```

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `using f1_t2 = decltype(&f1);`

Comment: Thank you very much @NathanOliver!